SQLAlchemy - psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName: no schema has been selected to create in
I am connecting a FastAPI and SQLAlchemy app to a postgres deployment using kubernetes.
I am specifying my connection string and schema as follows:
DB_URL = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{POSTGRES_USER}:{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@{DB}:5432/{DB_NAME}"

engine = create_engine(DB_URL, connect_args={"options":"csearch_path={}".format("schema_name")},)

However, upon application start up, I receive the following error:
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                        │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1967, in _exec_single_context                                                                                                  │
│     self.dialect.do_execute(                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 924, in do_execute                                                                                                          │
│     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName: no schema has been selected to create in                                                                                                                                     │
│ LINE 2: CREATE TABLE field (     

I don't understand why I am seeing this error when I am specifying a schema.

I think you might be missing the -, in front of csearch_path.  Something like this:
{"options":"-csearch_path={}".format("schema_name")}

Instead of:
{"options":"csearch_path={}".format("schema_name")}

You can also specify a default schema via metadata or per table which might be more convenient.
